# Is there any dump for wikipedia Pageid to wikidata id mapping?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

This page: http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/downloads/20160111/
has a dump called wikidatawiki-20160111-page-ids.ttl.bz2
which contains Wikidata id to what they called wikipage id. The wikipage id seems different from the Wikipedia pageid though.

e.g. for Germany:

- Wikipedia pageid = 11867
- Wikidata id = Q183 and wikipage id = 322.

So basically this dump maps Q183 to 322, while I need to map Q183 to 11867.

As a reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Germany&curid=11867 the curid in the URL represents the Wikipedia page id.

Is there any equivalent dump file out there that has the Wikidata ids and the Wikipedia pageid? (I don't want to use an API and loop my Wikipedia page id one by one like this one does: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&format=xml&pageids=11867)

**Edit:** I'm not sure about waht is exactly the wikipage id, but maybe there is a wikipageId to Wikipedia pageid mapping file on top of the dump I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the dump for the above request:
 https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20160720/
 there is a file there:
 enwiki-20160720-page_props.sql.gz
 the problem is the file is a MySql script, while i was looking for either a JSON or XML file. i Wrote a very short PHP script to extract the parenthesis blocks and have a format that fits my needs.

Answer (score 7):

I created a Python package and command line tool to deal with the issue called [wikimapper](https://github.com/jcklie/wikimapper). It can be installed via `pip install wikimapper`. It uses the Wikipedia SQL dumps to create an index that then can be used to map many times very fast (much faster than the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint). You could either use one of my [precomputed indices](https://public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/wikimapper/) and use this sqlite3 database or use the package to map Wikipedia page titles/Wikipedia URLs to Wikidata IDs and vice versa. Using pages names or URLs instead of interal Wikipedia IDs should be more comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to consider an API call solution instead of using the dump plus format adjustment, you could use the `pageprops` property of the `query` action.

For instance, if we want to find out the Wikidata item for Albert Einstein, given the wikipedia page title, you'd do:

```
 https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=pageprops&titles=Albert Einstein
```

Which gives:

```
 {
   "batchcomplete": "",
   "query": {
     "pages": {
       "736": {
         "pageid": 736,
         "ns": 0,
         "title": "Albert Einstein",
         "pageprops": {
           "defaultsort": "Einstein, Albert",
           "page_image": "Einstein_1921_by_F_Schmutzer_-_restoration.jpg",
           "wikibase-badge-Q17437798": "1",
           "wikibase_item": "Q937"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Like this we can retrieve the wikidata item id at `wikibase_item`.

(This is as originally answered by [Dmitry Brant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67808/dmitry-brant) in the [Mediawiki-api mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api))

Potentially this is a better solution because:

1. You only search for the items you need instead of having to search through the whole dump
2. You can get the answer in JSON or XML directly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am interested in the full scope want to stay away from the API.  
The fastest way i found so far is the following:  
enwiki-latest-page_props.sql.gz   dump file, then a very short PHP code to extract each parenthesis block.  Using the API is taking roughly a week to get everything, using the dump file + PHP regex brings it down to 15 min.

Comment: If you want the whole thing, then you're probably better off with the dump+extraction, I just thought that you might be interested in an actual (possibly small) subset of the whole dump.

Answer (score -1):

I found this link maybe helpful for you.

[enwiki dump progress on 20190401](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20190401/)

the link is: enwiki-20190401-wbc_entity_usage.sql.gz 212.5 MB

the format is like this:

```
(43094421,'P1070','C.P1630',78195)
```

which structure is:

```
`eu_row_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`eu_entity_id` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
`eu_aspect` varbinary(37) NOT NULL,
`eu_page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Hey,I found this file is not as useful as the upper ones:enwiki-20160720-page_props.sql.gz.I tried both ones. the format of the upper ones is very clear and cohesive.